# How to deploy using Zip Deploy instead of Web Deploy

Tags: azure

I have only one publish profile - Web Deploy.pubxml. It doesn't allow me to deploy to azure that is why I'd like to deploy using Zip Deploy.pubxml (My associate's publish profile is Zip Deploy.pubxml and he can deploy to azure)

I have `<WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>` on my WebDeploy.pubxml

My associate has `<WebPublishMethod>Zip Deploy</WebPublishMethod>` on his ZipDeploy.pubxml

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I used publish profile instead of creating new one from visual studio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2019